# Apache - How to get resources from the context path and not default when trying to get from /

Tags: apache, root, contextpath

I have various web application running on my apache server.

I can access the first web app by using `http://localhost:8080/app1/login`

But within the login page, I am trying to access an image, login.png as "/images/login.png". This tries to get the images from the default web app and not the web app on which it is currently working from.

I do not want to change the default web app of apache. Is there a way that I can access the image like "/images/login.png" and not as "/app1/images/login.png" or "../images/login.png"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or if you want to use a RewriteRule add this to your webserver roots .htaccess. This checks if the Requested filename is not a physical file or directory. if it's not. it redirects to your /app directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^/images/(.*) /app1/images/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi @Dennis Meissner, Thanks for your reply. But wouldn't doing this also change all the images which were supposed to be served from the ROOT (default) application to be also fetched from the "app1" application.

Comment: Therefor is the RewriteCond above. it first checks if the requested file exists physically as stated in my answer. Only if it does not exist it redirects into your /app1/images directory. Only if you have images of the same name in both directories, the root one will be sent  to output

Answer (score 0):

well if you are using it in html... then

```
./images/login.png
```

**EDIT:** 
Sorry I didnt see that you dont want to use that path... as other option can be using [modRewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)... you can rewrite your paths... so if you will use /login/image.jpg that can apache automatically rewrite for you as ./login/image.jpg